# Mongoose: Auto add Timestamps is raising an error $__isSelected is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to save some data to a mongoose collection and want the "createdAt" and "updatedAt" fields to automatically insert. Hence i added the **{ timestamps: true }** as the second parameter in the schema

This is my model schema

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const notificationSchema = new Schema(
  {
    type: String,
    author: String,
    metadata: Object,
    link: String
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = notificationSchema;
```

This is how i am inserting the records

```
 try {
    const notification = new Notification({
      type: "user",
      author: "phantom",
      metadata: {
        filename: "internet.png"
      },
      link: "http://yahoo.com"
    });
    const r = await notification.save();
    console.log(`r`, r);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

But I get this error and the data does not save

> this.$__isSelected is not a function

Stacktrace:

```
TypeError: this.$__isSelected is not a function
    at model.<anonymous> (/Users/phantom/projects/personal/backend/service1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/timestamps/setupTimestamps.js:54:69)
    at callMiddlewareFunction (/Users/phantom/projects/personal/backend/service1/src/submodules/node_modules/kareem/index.js:483:23)
    at model.next (/Users/phantom/projects/personal/backend/service1/src/submodules/node_modules/kareem/index.js:58:7)
    at _next (/Users/phantom/projects/personal/backend/service1/src/submodules/node_modules/kareem/index.js:107:10)
    at /Users/phantom/projects/personal/backend/service1/src/submodules/node_modules/kareem/index.js:508:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

When i dug up the **setupTimestamps.js** file at *node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/timestamps/setupTimestamps.js*, i saw this piece of code, which did not make any sense to me

```
if (!skipCreatedAt && createdAt && !this.get(createdAt) && this.$__isSelected(createdAt)) {
  this.$set(createdAt, auto_id ? this._id.getTimestamp() : defaultTimestamp);
}
```

When i make the { timestamps: false } then the record gets inserted without any error. I want mongoose to automatically create createdAt and modifiedAt fields automatically.

Did anyone faced this error before, and how did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` exists in `saveOptions` object so we can skip the timestamp for this save.

```
try {
  const notification = new Notification({
    type: "user",
    author: "phantom",
    metadata: {
      filename: "internet.png"
    },
    link: "http://yahoo.com"
  });
  const r = await notification.save({ timestamps: false });
  console.log(`r`, r);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Source: 
  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7960 
  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: setting it to false will NOT create createdAt and updatedAt fields, i want them to be created

Comment: Which mongoose version are you using ?

Comment: I am using mongoose version 5.11.8